# how to pass data using shared memory and save the received data to file

Tags: c, linux, file, process, shared-memory

I am new to linux environment. I just know the basics of C. I am trying to learn linux programming. For this I am trying an example on shared memory. Please someone help me with this example.
I am trying to send person details (like name, phone number & address) to another process using Shared memory. After receiving the data by the second process, I am trying to save received data into a file. This is the task I am doing. 
I am able to send just the name and receive it in the second process. Can someone please help how to send the data(like name, phone number & address) to second process and in the second process it must print the data and it should save the data to a file.
Here is my code:

```
address.c

char *shared_memory;
int main()
{
  int select;
  int segment_id;
  char* shared_memory;
  int segment_size;
  key_t shm_key;
  const int shared_segment_size = 0x6500;
  shm_key = ftok("/home/madan/programs/shm_tok",'C');
  if(shm_key < 0) {
    printf("failed to create the key %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  /* Allocate a shared memory segment. */
   segment_id = shmget (shm_key, shared_segment_size,
            IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(segment_id < 0) {
      printf("error geting the segment id %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }
    printf("segment ID:%d\n", segment_id);
   /* Attach the shared memory segment. */
   shared_memory = (char*) shmat (segment_id, 0, 0);
   printf ("shared memory attached at address %p\n", shared_memory);

/* I want to send these details to the shared memory. Can someone suggest me the correct way to send these details to shared memory so that second process can retrieve them*/

   sprintf(shared_memory, "maddy\n");
   sprintf(shared_memory, "767556686");
   sprintf(shared_memory, "Ontario");

 system("./address-insert");
      /* Detach the shared memory segment. */
  shmdt (shared_memory);
   /

    * Deallocate the shared memory segment.*/
           shmctl (segment_id, IPC_RMID, 0);
}
```

---

```
addres-insert.c

int main ()
{
  int segment_id;
  char* shared_memory;
  FILE *fp;
  char *name;
  int segment_size;
   key_t shm_key;
  shm_key = ftok("/home/madan/programs/shm_tok",'C');
  const int shared_segment_size = 0x6500;
  /* Allocate a shared memory segment. */
  segment_id = shmget (shm_key, shared_segment_size,
              S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  if(segment_id < 0) {
    printf("error:[%s]",strerror(errno));
  }
  printf("segment id %d\n",segment_id);
  /* Attach the shared memory segment. */
  shared_memory = (char*) shmat (segment_id, 0, 0);
  if(shared_memory == NULL) {
    printf("failed to attach the shared memory %s",strerror(errno));
  }
  printf ("shared memory2 attached at address %p\n", shared_memory);
  /* printing the data from shared memory send by first process*/
  printf ("name=%s\n", shared_memory);

  /*copying the data in shared memory so i can save them to a file*/
  strcpy(name, shared_memory);
  printf("%s", name);
  /*here i have to save the data to a file. But i don't know how to do it, can someone help me with this please*/

  /* Detach the shared memory segment. */
  shmdt (shared_memory);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shared memory is a rather clumsy way to do something like this.  You would find it much simpler to use a named pipe.  Then you can send the data items serially.  The pipe would handle all the synchronization issues you will have to perform manually with shared memory.

Comment: And if you're going to use shared memory, read a book or tutorial on the modern ways rather than reading 1980s-era X11 sources that use the old SysV `shmget` interface...

Comment: can't we send sequence of data(like name, phone number & address) to shared memory at a time and which should be received by the another process.

Comment: strcpy(name, shared_memory);
  printf("%s", name);
I want to copy data from shared_memory to a variable. Can I do this. Is this correct way to copy data from shared_memory to variable name.

Comment: amardeep & R.. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For saving the data in a file, you can use file stream. For that you have to know about file streams.

Hope these link will help.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Here comes the example program which I particularly typed, compiled and attached it for your reference.

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<stdio.h> 

struct mystruct // you can make your own structure if you want to pass many data
{
  int i;
  float f;
  char c;
  int arr[3];
}myObj = {1,1.1,'C',{100,1000,10000}};


main()
{
  int shmid;
  char* addr1;
  key_t key;
  //file to key. Generates a unique key
  key = ftok("/home/muthu/Desktop/anyfile.txt",'T');
  shmid = shmget(key,sizeof(struct mystruct),IPC_CREAT|SHM_R|SHM_W);
  printf("shmid = %d",shmid);
  addr1 = shmat(shmid,0,0);
  printf("\nIPC SHARED MEMORY");
  //copying your structure at the shared location.
  memcpy(addr1,&myObj,sizeof(myObj));
  printf("\nMESSAGE STORED");
}
```

And for shared memory 2.....

```
//<All necessary header files>
//<same my struct declaration here>
main()
{
  int shmid;
  char* addr1;
  FILE* fp;
  key_t key;

  struct mystruct* myObj2;
  //Generate the same unique key. Must provide the same file here too.
  key = ftok("/home/muthu/Desktop/anyfile.txt",'T');
  shmid = shmget(key,sizeof(struct mystruct),SHM_R|SHM_W);
  addr1 = shmat(shmid,0,0);
  myObj2 = (struct mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)*1);
  if(shmid == -1)
    printf("\nShared memory error");
  //Retrieve the stored information, form the shared location.
  memcpy(myObj2,addr1,sizeof(struct mystruct));
  fp = fopen("/home/muthu/Desktop/MyFile.txt","w"); //open a file stream
  if(fp == NULL) 
    printf("\nError on opening file stream.\n");
  fprintf(fp,"\nIPC SHARED MEMORY");
  fprintf(fp,"\nMESSAGE RECIEVED FORM THE SHARED MEMORY  IS..\n");
  fprintf(fp,"\ninteger: %d",myObj2->i);
  fprintf(fp,"\nfloat: %f",myObj2->f);
  fprintf(fp,"\nchar: %c",myObj2->c); //write to the file
  fprintf(fp,"\narr: %d %d %d",myObj2->arr[0],myObj2->arr[1],myObj2->arr[2]);
  fprintf(fp,"\nDATA RECIEVED.");  
  fclose(fp); //close the file stream
  printf("\nMessage successfully stored!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that you can use

```
fp = fopen("filename","a+");
fwrite(name, 1, strlen(name),fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your three fields onto a structure and load the structure onto the Shared Memory. In this way you are assured to have all the fields under one structure.

In the process that reads the SHM you can use the File Stream utils as mentioned above by others.

Comment: it was not allowing me as i am not a registered user.

Comment: @maddy you are registered user. But you doesnt have enough reputation. Atleast 15 reputation you must have